# ¿Cómo limitar la cadena de un input con jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Buenas tardes tengo las siguientes funciones para un input de mi formulario

```
$(function () {

 $("#cuenta_contable").on({
    "focus": function(event) {
      $(event.target).select();
    },
   "KeyPress": function(event) {
    $(event.target).val(function(index, value){
      if (this.value.length > 20) 
 this.value = this.value.slice(0,20);
    });  
   },

    "keyup": function(event) {
      $(event.target).val(function(index, value){

        return value.replace(/\D/g, "")
          .replace(/([0-9])$/, '$1')
          .replace(/\B(?=(\d{4})+(?!\d)\.?)/g, "-");

      });              

    }
  });

 $('.valida_formulario_cuenta').click(function () {
  return validar_formulario_cuenta($(this));
});
```

El problema que tengo es que si meten los valores solo presionando una tecla no respeta la función de limitar los caracteres a 20 pero si respeta el formato de la función de abajo.
Pero si meten los valores tecla por tecla si respeta las dos, como puedo hacer para que si lo meten de manera continua osea solo una tecla respete el max de 20 caracteres

Comment: a lo que entiendo necesitas que cuando introduzca menos de 20 caracteres se ejecute la otra función?

Comment: creo que no me explique bien las dos funciones funcionan correctamente si se meten los valores uno por uno pero si dejo presionado por ejemplo el 1 no respenta la funcion de solo 20 carcteres

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar esto
Primero css para que no aparesca flechas de numero en el input

```css
 input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
    input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button { 
    -webkit-appearance: none; 
    margin: 0; 
    }
 

aca limita los caracteres en el input minimo 20 mantengo una tecla presionada e igual admite 20 solo especifica la cantidad en maxlength
```

```html
<div > Ingresar Ruc</div>
 <div class="col-75">
<input type="number" name="ruc" onkeydown="return event.keyCode !== 69" oninput="if(this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);"   maxlength="20" class="form-control" id="ruc"  placeholder="ruc:" required=""></div>
```